# Bars are not fully shown / cut-off in bar graph tikzpicture

Tags: pgfplots, bar

I assume this is a simple fix, but I just don't see it at the moment.

I have four data sets (A,B,C,D), however the bars are not fully shown at x = 200 and x = 800.

Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\begin{document}

% Style to select only points from #1 to #2 (inclusive)
\pgfplotsset{select coords between index/.style 2 args={
    x filter/.code={
        \ifnum\coordindex<#1\def\pgfmathresult{}\fi
        \ifnum\coordindex>#2\def\pgfmathresult{}\fi
    }
}}

\pgfplotstableread{
    x       y       y+
    200     0.75    0.02
    400     0.76    0.01
    600     0.77    0.01
    800     0.77    0.01
    200     0.75    0.02
    400     0.75    0.01
    600     0.76    0.01
    800     0.76    0.01
    200     0.75    0.02
    400     0.75    0.01
    600     0.76    0.01
    800     0.76    0.01
    200     0.75    0.02
    400     0.75    0.01
    600     0.76    0.01
    800     0.76    0.01
}{\mytable}


\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline = (current bounding box.north)]
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        ymax=0.85,
        xlabel={-},        
        ylabel={-},
        xtick=data,
        xticklabels = {
            200,400,600,800
        },
        major x tick style = {opacity=0},
        minor x tick num = 1,
        minor tick length=2ex,
        legend style={anchor=north east},
        ]

        \addplot [ybar, fill=black!60] 
        plot [error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
        table[x index=0, y index=1, select coords between index={0}{3}, y error plus=y+, y error minus=y+]{\mytable};

        \addplot [ybar, fill=black!40] 
        plot [error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
        table[x index=0, y index=1, select coords between index={4}{7}, y error plus=y+, y error minus=y+]{\mytable};

        \addplot [ybar, fill=black!20] 
        plot [error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
        table[x index=0, y index=1, select coords between index={8}{11},y error plus=y+, y error minus=y+]{\mytable};

        \addplot [ybar, fill=black!10] 
        plot [error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
        table[x index=0, y index=1, select coords between index={12}{15},y error plus=y+, y error minus=y+]{\mytable};

    \legend{A,B,C,D}
    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

**Update after answer**

Thanks [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%C3%B8rn-t), your solution worked well.
Thanks for pointing out that I was mixing pgfplot and TikZ syntax.

I did some basic and useful research on pgfplot and TikZ syntax [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/pgfplots_package) (I should have done it before maybe).

**Adding more bars**

Maybe this is useful for someone else.

Eventually I wanted to have 6 bars in total, but the width of the 
graph did not update automatically.
Therefore I added the following to the axis options: `scale only axis` , `width=0.95\textwidth` `height=0.3\textwidth`.

[image: Graph with 6 bars and custom width]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\begin{document}

% Style to select only points from #1 to #2 (inclusive)
\pgfplotsset{select coords between index/.style 2 args={
    x filter/.code={
        \ifnum\coordindex<#1\def\pgfmathresult{}\fi
        \ifnum\coordindex>#2\def\pgfmathresult{}\fi
    }
}}

\pgfplotstableread{
    x       y       y+
    200     0.75    0.02
    400     0.76    0.01
    600     0.77    0.01
    800     0.77    0.01
    200     0.75    0.02
    400     0.75    0.01
    600     0.76    0.01
    800     0.76    0.01
    200     0.75    0.02
    400     0.75    0.01
    600     0.76    0.01
    800     0.76    0.01
    200     0.75    0.02
    400     0.75    0.01
    600     0.76    0.01
    800     0.76    0.01
    200     0.7    0.02
    400     0.7    0.01
    600     0.7    0.01
    800     0.7    0.01
    200     0.6    0.02
    400     0.6    0.01
    600     0.6    0.01
    800     0.6    0.01
}{\mytable}


\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline = (current bounding box.north)]
    \begin{axis}[
        scale only axis, 
        width=0.95\textwidth,
        height=0.3\textwidth,
        ybar,
        ymax=0.85,
        xlabel={-},        
        ylabel={-},
        xtick=data,
        xticklabels = {
            200,400,600,800
        },
        major x tick style = {opacity=0},
        minor x tick num = 1,
        minor tick length=2ex,
        legend style={
                at={(0.5,-0.4)}, 
                anchor=north, 
                legend columns=-1},
        enlarge x limits={abs=100},
        ]

        \addplot [fill=black!60,error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
        table[x index=0, y index=1, select coords between index={0}{3}, y error plus=y+, y error minus=y+]{\mytable};

        \addplot [fill=black!40,error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
        table[x index=0, y index=1, select coords between index={4}{7}, y error plus=y+, y error minus=y+]{\mytable};

        \addplot [fill=black!20,error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
        table[x index=0, y index=1, select coords between index={8}{11},y error plus=y+, y error minus=y+]{\mytable};

        \addplot [fill=black!10,error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
        table[x index=0, y index=1, select coords between index={12}{15},y error plus=y+, y error minus=y+]{\mytable};

        \addplot [fill=green!10,error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
        table[x index=0, y index=1, select coords between index={16}{19},y error plus=y+, y error minus=y+]{\mytable};

        \addplot [fill=blue!10,error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
        table[x index=0, y index=1, select coords between index={20}{23},y error plus=y+, y error minus=y+]{\mytable};

    \legend{A,B,C,D,E,F}
    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `enlarge x limits={abs={100}}` to the `axis` options.

On an unrelated note saying `\addplot plot` is mixing `pgfplots` and TikZ syntax, you only need `\addplot [<all the options>]`. And finally, when you have `ybar` in the `axis` options, it's not needed in each `\addplot`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\begin{document}

% Style to select only points from #1 to #2 (inclusive)
\pgfplotsset{select coords between index/.style 2 args={
    x filter/.code={
        \ifnum\coordindex<#1\def\pgfmathresult{}\fi
        \ifnum\coordindex>#2\def\pgfmathresult{}\fi
    }
}}

\pgfplotstableread{
    x       y       y+
    200     0.75    0.02
    400     0.76    0.01
    600     0.77    0.01
    800     0.77    0.01
    200     0.75    0.02
    400     0.75    0.01
    600     0.76    0.01
    800     0.76    0.01
    200     0.75    0.02
    400     0.75    0.01
    600     0.76    0.01
    800     0.76    0.01
    200     0.75    0.02
    400     0.75    0.01
    600     0.76    0.01
    800     0.76    0.01
}{\mytable}


\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline = (current bounding box.north)]
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        ymax=0.85,
        xlabel={-},        
        ylabel={-},
        xtick=data,
        xticklabels = {
            200,400,600,800
        },
        major x tick style = {opacity=0},
        minor x tick num = 1,
        minor tick length=2ex,
        legend style={anchor=north east},
        enlarge x limits={abs=100}
        ]

        \addplot [fill=black!60,error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
        table[x index=0, y index=1, select coords between index={0}{3}, y error plus=y+, y error minus=y+]{\mytable};

        \addplot [fill=black!40,error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
        table[x index=0, y index=1, select coords between index={4}{7}, y error plus=y+, y error minus=y+]{\mytable};

        \addplot [fill=black!20,error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
        table[x index=0, y index=1, select coords between index={8}{11},y error plus=y+, y error minus=y+]{\mytable};

        \addplot [fill=black!10,error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
        table[x index=0, y index=1, select coords between index={12}{15},y error plus=y+, y error minus=y+]{\mytable};

    \legend{A,B,C,D}
    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```